# Group By Column returns two rows of the same value

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I have a MySQL DB (which is supposed to be in alphabetic order) that contains, English nouns, and their corresponding categories, like food, animals etc. I run the following query so that I can get one from each category;

```
SELECT english, word, category FROM dict GROUP BY category
```

The result I get is the following;

[image: Query Result]

Its been driving me nuts now, but why are there repetitions of the category Animals, Shapes, Stationaries etc., when I'm grouping by category?

Help me out please.

Additional Info: When I run this query;

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dict WHERE category = 'Animals'
```

It returns the value 1, but as you can see from the image, it should return more than one. Why are two words which look exactly the same, i.e 'Animals', considered different?

Comment: MySQL database tables are part of a relational database. These tables have no order by themselves.

Comment: Perhaps some categories have spaces before or after the word? Try: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dict WHERE category LIKE '%Animals%'`.

Comment: Damn, you're right. Your query returns 2. But I don't understand, no space is visible, I mean, at least when the use a cursor and select the whole thing.

Comment: Well you found the cause. You can use a query to get rid of extra stuff: `UPDATE dict SET category = TRIM(category)`. Please make a backup first!

Comment: Solved it. Thank you so much!

Comment: This query `SELECT english, word, category FROM dict GROUP BY category` is wrong. you shouldn't use this query at all

Comment: Why so? I'm pretty new to this.

Comment: Because this query doesn't makes sense. this is wrong grouping

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @KIKO Software. There seemed to be some sort of invisible character in some of the categories. Fixed it with the TRIM function.

```
UPDATE dict SET category = TRIM(category)
```